# Base 64 image stored with html body, is not getting while emailing

Tags: c#, html, sql-server, email

I have a rad-editor in ASPX page, while writing some text and adding screen shot its saved in DB as like in pic-1. I need to send it as email but whatever email I'm getting its showing the that content only not image. (Pic-2). In code I'm specifying html format.

And code is pic-3

How solve it.

Thanks in advance. 
(Note: Ex of saved data and email i'm getting are different)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you wants to mail you should attach only Base64 string to the email.

```
Eg.  "data:image/jpeg;base64,YourStringHere"
```

Comment: Thanks.
You mean to add content like below.

Test&nbsp;<br />  <br />  "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEU...

i tried not getting

Comment: i mean in place of content just pass this "data:image/jpeg;base64,YourStringHere"

Comment: if this is not working then another solution you can try. Create file of that base64 string and store somewhere.So you can attach that file path to the Email.